# DS3400 - no access - only ping via management ethernet port

Tags: storage-area-network, ibm

This is my first post, so sorry if I `ll miss something

My task is to collect data from few years old DS3400+EXP3000 ( it was disconnected from power last 2 years).

After starting it on front panels are only green leds on both devices, so I assume that system is ok ( no any LED lighting on HDD).

Unfortunately there is almost no connection with the devise - Fibe /channel is dead ( after connection no LED links) and managemet ethernet port ( it was set to 10.0.0.188)  only pinging ok ( there is also 513 port open on this IP) - connected directly to my laptop ( no switch)

I've tried connect vua putty ( SSH / Telnet) - "connection refused" and IBM DS Storage management  V 10.35.G5.37 doesn't find this device automatically and via manual add - use it as Unknown ( I`ve installed it on windows 10 PC instead Windows server 2008 - maybe this is problem...)

One more think - on one of controller ( only this one pingig) there is battery orange LED  lighting.

Could you please support me with this case if possible ?

Regards + take care in those hard Covid Times
Bartek

[Rear leds of DS3400](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rygxv.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

There are some steps you can take to try and establish a connection to the storage device.
My first advice would be to establish a serial connection via the serial port located at the back of the device, you will need a serial cable to do that.
You will need to plug the serial cable to any one of the 2 controllers and establish a serial connection using this settings -

baud rate to 9600
flow control none
stop bit 8

The default password and login are  -  shellUsr or admin , pass - wy3oo&w4 or - infiniti

once you get a serial connection you can check the IP address of both controllers - netCfgShow
(if you are not able to open a serial connection to the device there is a serious issue)
The other option/step is -

1. Try to connect to port 2 on each ethernet port of controllers A and B
2. Setup your Ethernet card in the computer with an IP 192.168.129.3 or you will need a mini hub to create a network (individual depending on your setup)
3. Ping IP 192.168.129.1 or 192.168.129.0 (default)
4. If there is a ping open Putty and try to make telnet session. It is possible telnet not to be enabled , then you can try directly to add the DS to SM (you can then allow telnet to the controllers from the SM )
5. It does not matter the version of Windows. Windows 10 works normal with Storage manager. Better download the latest version of SM version 11.20
6. Battery orange indicator means the battery is dead and needs to be replaced, but this is not a reason for any connectivity issue

This are only suggestions for professional support please go to -
"https://www.ibm.com/mysupport/s/"

You may also follow me at @MilenHristovHr1

Regards MIlen